# Event.target alternatives

Tags: javascript, html

I try to make side navigation close on click somewhere but navigation block itself and its toggle button. I try such code:

**HTML**

```
<div class="header__menu-toggle">
    <div class="icon-menu"></div>
</div>
<section id="main-nav">
  <ul class="main-nav__inner">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

**NATIVE JS**

```
var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var nav = document.getElementById('main-nav');
var navToggle = document.getElementsByClassName('header__menu-toggle')[0];

function closeAll(e) {
    if (e.target != nav && e.target != navToggle) {
        nav.classList.remove("main-nav--open");
    }
}

body.addEventListener('click', closeAll)
```

The problem is that `e.target` equals to an exact target of click, not whole block. For ex. click on `<div class="icon-menu"></div>` is not equal click on its parent `<div class="header__menu-toggle">`. Or click on child `li` elements deep in navigation block isn't equal to click on `<section id="main-nav">`.
How to solve this problem? How to check if I click on navigation block or navToggle block in common?

Comment: You better wrap the entire thing in its own container and apply the event listener to it. Applying it on the `body` is a not a good idea. It may solve your original problem as well.

Answer (score 0):

try : $(event.currentTarget)
i think that is the solution , if not try to display the event object and find some sub-property of event that help you
this link can help
[event.currentTarget](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget)

Comment: It is a good answer if OP uses jQuery but I think the question applies mainly to native js.

Comment: yes but event.currentTarget is a native js that i just copied from my js code

Comment: However, $(event.currentTarget) is jquery.

Answer (score 0):

I guess something like this may work.

Side note: `querySelector` and `querySelectorAll` are great, use them instead.

```js
var body = document.querySelector("body");
var nav = document.querySelector('#main-nav');
var navToggle = document.querySelector('.header__menu-toggle');
var nodeArr = [].slice.call(nav.childNodes);

function closeAll(e) {
  if (nodeArr.indexOf(e.target) !== -1) {
    console.log('closing the nav')
    nav.classList.remove("main-nav--open");
  } else {
    console.log('clicked inside nav')
  }
}

body.addEventListener('click', closeAll)
```

```html
<div class="header__menu-toggle">
    <div class="icon-menu"></div>
</div>
<section id="main-nav">
  <ul class="main-nav__inner">
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
    <li>three</li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

**Why it works?**

`nav.childNodes` stores information about all children of the nav element. We convert it to array for convenience. After `click` is detected we check if the click target belongs to the nav (is in the array).

Answer (score 0):

Try to go up in DOM tree from target element.

```js
//function search for "search" element for "current" element and all his parents
function isInside(search,current){

    if (current!=search){
      
        if (typeof current.parentNode != 'undefined' && current.parentNode!=null)
        return isInside(search,current.parentNode);//go to parent
        else
          return false;//our tree is over - this is outside element
      
    }else{
        //yes this is element we looking for
        return true;
    }
  
};
   
var search=document.querySelector("#container");

//usage
document.querySelector("body").addEventListener("click",function(e){
 
      if (isInside(search,e.target)){
          console.log("click inside #container");
      }else{
          console.log("click outside #container");
      }
});
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div> This is wrong div</div>
<div id="container" width="100px" height="100px" style="display:block; background:red"><ul><li><span>Test node</span></li></ul>
  
</div>
  <div> This is wrong div</div>
</body>  
</html>
```

Explanation - i start with e.target node and go up, there are to endings - one if we find parent which is matching searching element - this means we are inside or we are this element, or second we go to end of tree - we are outside.

> This method can be improved by adding for example how much levels we should go up.

In this current problem usage of **isInside** function would be like this:

```
function closeAll(e) {
   if (!isInside(nav,e.target) && !isInside(navToggle,e.target) ) {
      nav.classList.remove("main-nav--open");
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

event.path return array of tree structure which can be used to find parents of target element.

replace js code with :

```
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0];
var nav = document.getElementById('main-nav');
var navToggle = document.getElementsByClassName('header__menu-toggle')[0];

function closeAll(event) {
    if (event.path.indexOf(nav) > -1 && event.path.indexOf(navToggle) > -1) {
        nav.classList.remove("main-nav--open");
    }
}

body.addEventListener('click', closeAll)
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use jquery method "closest"

```
$(document).click( function(event){
   if( $(event.target).closest("#main-nav").length ||           
       $(event.target).closest(".header__menu-toggle").length) return;

       $("#main-nav").removeClass("main-nav--open");  
}
```